# inject java script files to index.html page in particular order but its injecting in different way?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

Injecting files like this :

```
[<script src="/js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular-flexslider.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular-google-maps.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular-material.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular-material.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular-scroll.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular-slick.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular-spinkit.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular.headroom.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/backgroundVideo.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/calcumateemi.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/covervid.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/custom.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/geometry.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/headroom.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/jquery.fullPage.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/lodash.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/mapapi.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/markerLabel.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/ng-map.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/ng-youtube-embed.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/ngInfiniteScroll.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/sim.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/slick.min.js"></script>
     <script src="/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.1.js"></script>](url)
```

so my code is :

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    gulp.src("client/js/*.js")
        .pipe(order(['client/js/angular.min.js',
            'client/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js',
            'client/js/ngStorage.min.js',
            'client/js/angular-scroll.min.js',
            'client/js/angular-material.min.js',
            'client/js/angular-animate.min.js',
            'client/js/angular-aria.min.js',
            'client/js/angular-messages.min.js',
            'client/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.0.1.js',
            'client/js/ng-youtube-embed.min.js',
            'client/js/bootstrap.min.js',
            'client/js/slick.min.js',
            'client/js/headroom.js',
            'client/js/angular.headroom.js',
            'client/js/angular-route.min.js',
            'client/js/angular-slick.min.js',
            'client/js/slick.min.js',
            'client/js/angular-cookies.min.js',
            'client/js/ngInfiniteScroll.js',
            'client/js/angular-spinkit.min.js',
            'client/js/angular-scroll.min.js',
            'client/js/lodash.js'
             ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build/js/'));
});


gulp.task('index',function () {
    return gulp.src('client/index.html')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(['build/js/*.js','build/css/*.css'], {read: false}), {ignorePath: 'build'}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
        .pipe(livereload());
})

gulp.task('default', ['js','css', 'index','browser-sync','watch']);
```

i used inject order but not injecting in that order ,so any modifications please,and i am not using any bower.
so how can i inject that pipe order files injection   .pipe(order(['',''...]) 
any help please

my folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

adding [base](https://github.com/sirlantis/gulp-order#base) can fix .Just give it a try:

```
  .pipe(order([
      'public/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js',
      'public/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    ], { base: './' }))
```

Comment: thanq for rply ,i tried as per your suggestion but no change.